# Storing TfIdf model and then loading it to test the new dataset

Tags: python, tf-idf, joblib, tfidfvectorizer

I m trying to store the TfIdf vectorizer/model(Don't know whether it is a right word or not) obtained after training the dataset and then loading the stored model to fit the new dataset.
Model is stored and loaded using pickle

I have stored the vocabulary of TfIdf obtained during training phase. Then, I load the stored the vocabulary to vectorizer to fit the test data

```
def Savetfidf(df):
    vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=0.0, analyzer="char", sublinear_tf=True, ngram_range=(1,2))
    X = pd.SparseDataFrame(vectorizer.fit_transform(df), columns = vectorizer.get_feature_names(), default_fill_value = 0)
    pickle.dump(vectorizer.vocabulary_, open("features.pkl", "wb"))
    return X

def Loadtfidf(df):
    vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=0.0, analyzer="char", sublinear_tf=True, ngram_range=(1,2))
    vocabulary = pickle.load(open(feature, 'rb'))
    vectorizer.vocabulary_ = vocabulary
    X = pd.SparseDataFrame(vectorizer.transform(df), columns = vectorizer.get_feature_names(), default_fill_value = 0)
    return X
```

I m getting an error

"sklearn.exceptions.NotFittedError: idf vector is not fitted"

As far as I got to know, it is trying to save the whole 'X' separately using  idf_ and vocabulary_. But I just want to store the model/vectorizer(Don't know) so that when next time it load the model/vectorizer, I just need to call vectorizer.fit() for the test data, no need to use the training data to   call fit_transform().
Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Following the instructions [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html), you can (un)pickle the fitted `vectorizer` object directly, and it will take care of correct (de)serialization on its own.

Comment: I m trying to transform a dataset from string to numeric, the link which you have posted shows the method of saving and loading the classifier model which is way different from what I m trying to do

Comment: @HarshBhagwani that is just an example, it works with all scikit models

Answer (score 0):

If you dump your model which is vectorizer.fit_transform(df) and also dump vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=0.0, analyzer="char", sublinear_tf=True, ngram_range=(1,2)). Then in Loadtfidf() load both the pickle file. This will solve your problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).